# Android Services

Tags: android

i am having some problems with services in android , here is the structure of Activities which i am loading in my app .

1. FirstActivity--->MusicPlayer---->ServiceToPlayMusic

when i navigate back from MusicPlayer Activity to firstActivity .

FirstActivity <------MusicPlayer.

Service runs in background but the activity on which i bound that service was crashed (MusicPlayer)
i want to update the UI of MusicPlayer Activity

any Suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Message and AsyncTask to update the UI from Services